# Scrollview scroll down when NativeExpressAdView load

Tags: android, admob, scrollview

I use Admob NativeExpressAdView in my scrollview bottom. But when it load new ad my scrollview scroll to adview. But I don't want this. How can I stop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of support library version 25.1.0 the only available solution is to move NativeExpressAdView outside of any ScrollView container as it will receive focus since NativeExpressAdView is rendered in a WebView. Even if you try to apply android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to ScrollView it will not help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

I just add this in main child Layout of scrollview.
Here is the sample code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
            android:id="@+id/adViewNative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="360x320"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-..."></com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```